# $_GET from URL without file extension

Tags: php

I just can't figure out, how to make this work.

I have a main page into which I am including other pages, creating URL's without file extensions:

```
switch ($_GET['page'])
{
  case "search":
    include "pages/search.php";
  break;
}
```

Then I have a GET form sending a value from the main page to the one included.

The URL looks like this: **www.page.com/search?word=value** but based on **var_dump($_GET)** there is no **$_GET['word']**.

Comment: What is the value of `$_REQUEST['word']`?

Comment: your design is wrong, mate. Look mod_rewrite if you're using apache server...

Comment: Are you using mod_rewrite? Perhaps you need to use the `[QSA]` flag?

Comment: It isn't obvious. `mkdir search; touch search/index.php`.

Comment: @AD7six why do you say he's already using mod rewrite? i see no hints of that anywhere and in fact it looks like he's trying to achieve the same result of a mod_rewrite-like approach. That's why I said that his design was wrong

Comment: @Alvin Wong - Thanks, that was it. I didn't know about that obiously :( Btw, sorry guys, I totally forgot to include to include my .htaccess options.

Comment: @AD7six and that's exactly why i said it wasn't obvious ;) anyway, it's better to be sure, to presume is the first step of being wrong.

Comment: @STT LCU he was right. I am indeed using rewrite to do this. Just forgot to mention it. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you described it looks like you are using `.htaccess` to redirect the requests from  `/search` to `/index.php?page=search`.

If that's the case, you are probably looking for `[QSA]` mod_rewrite flag. Read the documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa.

Comment: How do you get that from "including other pages"?

Comment: From the URL OP posted: www.page.com/search?word=value

Comment: Oh hell... yep, I totally forgot to mention my .htaccess rewrite options. Ups. Thanks btw, that was it.