# $_GET attribute from URL without question mark

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using plain PHP with no frameworks at all, I want the visitor of my website to access with specific order number, Ex:

http://example.com/index.php?order=123

but I want it to be like this

http://example.com/123


I've found here what I need

[$_GET from URL without file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316098/get-from-url-without-file-extension)


but I couldn't understand how to merge it with my current htaccess file, my file currently contains this code which redirect all the http requests to https


this is the code of it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I hope I've explained my question properly, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use PHP **URL redirect** for **value integer**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) index.php?order=$1 [NC,L]
```

you can use PHP **URL redirect** for value  **alphabet**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+) index.php?order=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You try rewrite url in htaccess, with your issue:

> RewriteRule (.+) index.php?order=$1 [L]

Let view documents in [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)